# DataTable and ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datatable, repeater

I am binding a DataTable to a repeater. However when I run my aspx page it is not evaluating the Eval statements and displaying them on the page as

```
<<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %> Posted by: <<%# Eval("UserName").ToString() %>
<<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %> Posted by: <<%# Eval("UserName").ToString() %>
<<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %> Posted by: <<%# Eval("UserName").ToString() %>
```

It is also breaking it down to 3 rows. Which is also not what I had expected. I thought it would display as spans normally would

I have taken out the .ToString to check if it was that causing the issue. But it was not.

Below is my Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="First" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="ItemDiv">
                <span class="ItemLeft"></span>
                <span class="ItemCentre">
                    <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </span>
                <span class="ItemRight">
                    <asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text='<<%# Eval("UserName").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The code to bind is the following:

```
public void dataLoad()
{
    DataTable Data = loadData(1,1,1);

    if (Data.Rows.Count < 10)
    {
        // Only populate the data from datatable
        First.DataSource = Data;
        First.DataBind();
        Second.Visible = false;
        noData.Visible = true;
    }
```

I have changed some of the names in the above example

In the Debug information I can see that my DataTable is using the correct column names, and that these match my eval statements.

I know I have created this in a rather strange way, from what I have read, and researched online it is more common to use a table rather than Divs/or Spans for this. So I am aware that that may be the problem at its heart.

I cannot see why it would be any different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `<<` from your eval statements. It should be:

```
<div class="ItemDiv">
    <span class="ItemLeft"></span>
    <span class="ItemCentre">
        <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </span>
    <span class="ItemRight">
        <asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </span>
</div>
```